# Ignore saturday value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that does the following:

1. Checks the date in Col K
2. If the date is a Sunday and if the "P" col has the text "Moved to SA",
    it will not color the values in Col M in red.

Example format: `M/D/YYY TIME - 1/22/2017 21:00`

What I want to add to the above logic is:

- The code should also check for Saturday along with the time 
  i.e. If the time on Saturday is more than 6PM (18:00), then it should not color the value in Col M.

I just need to add this one condition in my code.

```
Sub SundayDatefilter()

Dim r, lastrow, remainingDay As Long

lastrow = Range("M:P").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For r = 2 To lastrow
      remainingDay = 0

     If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
        remainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

        If InStr(1, Range("P" & r).Text, "*Moved to SA*", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           If Range("M" & r) - remainingDay >= 1 Then
              Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
           Else
              Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
           End If
        End If
     End If
  Next r
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, there is no need to add that test :

- Your first test is to check if the date is a SUNDAY
- If it is not, you won't go further for that row
- So if the date is a SATURDAY, you won't color anything!

I've modified a bit your code :

- As you declared your variables `r` and `lastrow` were `Variant`s!
- I've added a reference to the sheet (here `Sheet1`) to increase robustness and performance

Here is your code :

```
Sub SundayDatefilter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wS As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    RemainingDay As Long

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With wS
    LastRow = .Range("M:P").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   For r = 2 To LastRow
      RemainingDay = 0
        If Weekday(.Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
            RemainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(.Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

            If InStr(1, .Range("P" & r).Text, "*Moved to SA*", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                If .Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                    .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If Weekday(.Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 7 and TimeValue(.Range("K" & r))>TimeValue("18:00:00") Then
            RemainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(.Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

            If InStr(1, .Range("P" & r).Text, "*Moved to SA*", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                If .Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                    .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End With 'wS
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. What If I need to color SATURDAY (entries after 18:00) , if it is greater than 1? @R3uK

Comment: It works for SATURDAY. But How will it check the time I need to color it only if the time is more than 18:00

Comment: @stackmark : Apparently, you didn't see the 2nd test : `TimeValue(.Range("K" & r))>TimeValue("18:00:00")` ;)